# How do I Call Chrome Extension from C# in headless mode

Tags: c#, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a C# application which can call a chrome extension api.

My chrome extension api mainly tries to check if the user has turned on sync.

I need to call chrome extension from c# application and check the status of turn on my sync is enabled 
in headless mode for chrome and pass it on to c# application

I know we can communicate with Native messaging protocol from chrome extension to c#. But how do we call chrome extension from c#?

Is it possible?Is there any example?

Comment: The nativeMessaging API provides a way for extensions to run an external program like your C# app and **then** communicate via stdio. There's no other way.

Comment: So if i understand you correctly, i can only call the C# method from javascript. I will not be able to do it in reverse way -> calling javascript functions from c#

Comment: Your C# app can respond to your extension's call as shown in the documentation and linked examples.